# Linux VM connect to Gigabit Eth Switch

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, virtual-machine, gigabit-ethernet

I am running VMWare Workstation 7.1.0 build-261024 on Windows XP. I have an Ubuntu 11.10 set up as a VM.

I have connected the Windows XP PC and a Cisco 1252 AP (without DHCP) to a gigbit ethernet switch.

I wish to have the Ubuntu VM connected to the switch as well.

I've created a network interface which does that, however due to the fact there's no DHCP, I can't obtain an IP.

I've added an additional USB NIC and connected it as a "USB Device" to the Ubuntu VM and set a static IP on that, but I cannot ping the host PC nor can I ping the IP.

Is there any way I can allow my Ubuntu VM to be connected to the gigabit switch without DHCP?

Thanks,

Parth

Comment: Presumably you mean VMWare Workstation 7.1.0? VMWare is a company not a product.

Comment: You're right, I meant VMWare Workstation. I've updated my original post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to configure Virtual switch in VMware workstation;
2. Assign a network card that is connected to Giggabit switch to Virtual Switch;
3. Configure Ubuntu VM to use that Virtual switch;
4. Configure Static IP in Ubuntu.

There is no need to use USB NIC.

Comment: With that configuration, I am unable to set a static IP in Ubuntu, that's why I tried adding a USB NIC

Comment: if you have a GUI: [link](http://www.muktware.com/2686/setting-network-ubuntu-1110) and from shell: [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/static-ip-under-ubuntu-11-10-a-918165/)

Comment: Through GUI it says device not managed

Comment: can you make a screen shot of your VM configuration?

Comment: http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=2961

This works to set the static IP. after editing the file, I did a sudo iface eth0 up and I can access my apache server

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please close the question.